# Как 'подружить' header() и $_SESSION?

Tags: php, сессия, redirect, header

Имеется код:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'functions.php';

# КОЛИ

# авторизація
if (isset($_POST['user']) AND isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $id = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    if (read_pass($pdo,$id,md5($pass)) == 'OK') {
        $key = md5(time().md5($pass.md5($id)));
        add_key($pdo,$id,$key);
        $_SESSION['key'] = $key;
        echo "autorised!";
    } else {
        echo "bad password!";
    }
# вихід
} elseif (isset($_POST['exit']) AND $_POST['exit'] == 'Вихід') {
    unset($_SESSION['key']);
    session_unset();
    echo "exit - ok!";
}

header("Location :".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); //строка 27
?>
```

при таком коде возникает ошибка:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   X:\home\localhost\www\kbm\adm\event-listener.php:24) in
>   X:\home\localhost\www\kbm\adm\event-listener.php on line 27

Как я понимаю хедер и сессии конфликтуют. Когда я Удаляю либо session_start() либо header() то ошибки нету, но код работает не правильно. Как сделать так чтобы был и session_start() и header()?

Comment: с чего ты взял, что `header` ругается из-за `session_start`, а не твои `echo`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я закоментировал `echo` и оно все равно не работает. Сам хедер не перенаправляет на предыдущую страницу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите любой вывод до header (). Это ограничение http протокола.

Comment: Убрал. Код отрабатывает нормально и без ошибок но редирект не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ничего не выводи до отправки заголовков.
2. `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` далеко не всегда что-то содержит. Сделай проверку:

   ```
   if( !empty( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ] ) ) {
       header( "Location: " . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ] );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

у меня была похожая проблема, решил ее когда перевел кодировку на "UTF8 без BOM"
вот есть статья советую ознакомиться для более точного понимания:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Вот кстати кусок от туда:

"Наличие BOM в PHP скриптах приводит к тому, что HTTP заголовки отправляются в браузер до начала выполнения кода. Это вызывает ошибки при попытке в дальнейшем коде отправить заголовок (например переадресацию или код ответа)."